# Facebook login from android to node js server using passport

Tags: android, node.js, facebook, passport.js, passport-facebook

i wanna login with facebook from my android application to my node js back-end witch is configurate with passport js

```
app.route('/auth/facebook').get(passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        scope: ['email']
    }));
    app.route('/auth/facebook/callback').get(users.oauthCallback('facebook'));
```

and it's work in the front-end side
But i wanna know how to login with my android application using passport js

Should i use facebook SDK or not !!

Comment: I've got the same question. Let me know if you figured it out! Thanks!

Comment: yes i figured it out :
-first you have to login from android app using facebook sdk
-second, you have to get the access token of the user
-then, you have to post this access token to your node server (access_token)
-and finally you have to use passport-facebook-token module in the server side
i hope this help you
if you have any problems please contact me (oussama.jebali@esprit.tn)

Comment: Can you help with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32661411/passport-facebook-giving-two-different-facebook-id