# Passport-Facebook giving two different facebook Id

Tags: node.js, facebook, mongodb, sails.js, passport-facebook

I tried to implement `facebook` `OAUTH` for my applications(Web and Mobile) using Sails.js/Node.js and Mongo as my backend. I wrote a dedicated function to access the `endpoints` for each app cause the webApp needs a callback URL and the mobile doesn't. My code screenshot is available below. But, I noticed the two gives me two different Facebook id. I am confused, shouldn't the facebookId be unique? I am using these two modules
`FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy`
`FacebookTokenStrategy = require('passport-facebook-token').Strategy`

WebApp `Strategy`

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
clientID      : facebook.clientID,
clientSecret  : facebook.clientSecret,
profileFields : ['id', 'email', 'last_name', 'first_name', 'gender', 'link', 'verified', 'updated_time', 'timezone', 'age_range'],
passReqToCallback: true
},
function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
authenticate(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done);
}
));
```

The `authenticate function being pointed at`

```
 var authenticate = function (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
User.findOne({facebookId: profile.id}).then(function (user){
    if (user) {
        return [user, {accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken}]
    } else {
        var data = {
            facebookId: profile.id,
            firstname: profile._json.first_name,
            lastname: profile._json.last_name,
            email: profile._json.email,
            gender: profile._json.gender,
            fb_profile_url: profile._json.link,
            fb_verified: profile._json.verified,
            fb_updated_time: profile._json.updated_time,
            phonenumber: profile._json.phone
        }
        var userQry = User.create(data);
    }
    return [userQry, {accessToken: accessToken, refreshToken: refreshToken}]
})
.spread(function (user, credentials){
    if (user) {
        return done(null, [user, credentials]);
    } else {
        return done(null, null);
    }
})
.catch(function (err){
    return done(err, null);
});
}
```

[image: MobileApp Strategy]

Comment: Are the two different apps using different facebook app ids?

Comment: Nope. They're not using two different ids @WizKid

Comment: Are you absolute sure about that? (If so, report a bug.) Otherwise, with two different apps, that was to be expected – it’s called app-scoped user ids.

Comment: Very sure. And same app, just multiple platforms